# How to efficiently make app-engine-ndb subqueries on properties of KeyProperty linked entities?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

An assembled Team may be deployed over time to multiple Projects

In this example I want to query for Teams assigned to 'active' projects only. The code I am using is working, but I would like to know if there is a more efficient / compact means of doing so.

**Models**

```
class Team(ndb.Model):
    """Model for representing an project team."""
    teamid = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    project = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Project', required=True, repeating=True)

class Project(ndb.Model):
    """Model for representing a Project"""
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    status = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
```

**Query**

```
status = 'active'

project_query = Project.query()\
    .filter(Project.status == status)

active_projects = project_query.fetch(1000, keys_only=True)

team_query = Team.query().order(Team.teamid)\
    .filter(Team.projectid.IN(active_projects))

results = team_query.fetch(max_results, offset=start_at)
```

**Compact form** (*essentially the same thing*)

```
team_query = Team.query().order(Team.teamid)\
    .filter(Team.projectid.IN(Project.query().filter(Project.status == status)
        .fetch(1000, keys_only=True)))
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Checking [appstats](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats?hl=en) would be your best way to tell for sure. You should definitely do a `keys_only=` query for active projects and then use those keys in a query for `Team`.

Comment: that's what I am doing already. the compact form is not any different to compare - i was wondering if there was a fundamentally different way to handle it

Comment: Nope, your way is the most efficient given the context in your post.

Comment: actually the compact form is dubious as it fails if the project query is empty

Comment: The alternate way would be to store the keys of Teams whilst related in the project.  And then query active projects, you then have the teams..

Comment: but this would still require a mapping query to return other properties of the teams no?

Comment: Yes.  You need to consider from an efficiency point of view what you need.  In some cases a linking entity (stores keys to the team and the project and whatever summary data you need) could be more efficient.  The no mapping required unless you need to drill down.  All the results for the first view would be in a single query.

Comment: Can a Project have multiple Teams, or just one?

Comment: A project has multiple teams. A team can be utilised on multiple projects

Answer (score 3):

You could de-normalize your data model by "redundantly" having a `project_status` property on the Team entity as well, maintained to be the same as the `status` property on the corresponding Project entity.

The downside of course is that "changing a Project's status" also needs to find all Teams assigned to that Project and correspondingly change their project_status (and you may need a multiple-entity-groups transaction for that). But the big upside is that locating all Teams assigned to Projects in a certain status becomes much faster, a single simple query.

This trade-off is pretty typical for decisions related to de-normalizing data models. If, in your application, Project status changes relatively rarely (and perhaps typically few Teams are assigned to a given Project), while queries for "all Teams assigned to Projects in a certain status" are frequent and need to be fast, then the de-normalization will be a worthy optimization.

Waxing even more abstract, which de-normalizations are worthwhile is always highly dependent on specific application constraints -- which queries or updates are rare or frequent, what performance goals are there for each operation. You also always pay the price of having slightly more data around, since a few things are duplicated. On the other hand, many applications have relatively rare writes/updates, and pretty frequent reads/queries, which does tend to favor judicious de-normalizations.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have a many-to-many relationship between Teams and Projects, it's your choice whether to have Teams with:

```
project = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Project', required=True, repeating=True)
```

or Projects with:

```
team = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Team', required=True, repeating=True)
```

You can improve on your query-in-a-query by using only one query and an ndb.get_multi().  Queries are slow, Gets are faster (especially when memcached).  By changing your models, you can improve your queries.

```
class Team(ndb.Model):
    """Model for representing an project team."""
    teamid = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)

class Project(ndb.Model):
    """Model for representing a Project"""
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    status = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    team = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Team', required=True, repeating=True)
```

Now you can query by status and perform a get:

```
status = 'active'

project_query = Project.query()\
    .filter(Project.status == status)

active_projects = project_query.fetch(1000, keys_only=True)

teams = set()
for project in active_projects:
    teams.extend(project.team)

results = ndb.get_multi(list(teams))
```

(Credit to Tim Hoffman for commenting on this approach.)